# ServiceStack exception on simple service

Tags: .net, servicestack

I am just trying to create a simple service like the HelloWorld one. However, AppHost is throwing:

```
Method 'Add' in type 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRoutes' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=3.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;
using Funq;

namespace Eagle
{
  public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
  {

      public class TestAppHost : AppHostBase
      {
          //Tell Service Stack the name of your application and where to find your web services
          public TestAppHost() : base("Test Web Services", typeof(TestService).Assembly) { }

          public override void Configure(Container container)
          {
              //register user-defined REST-ful urls
              Routes
                .Add<Test>("/test")
                .Add<Test>("/test/{Name}");
          }
      }


      protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          try
          {
              new TestAppHost().Init();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Routes.Add<T>` is an extension method in the `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface` namespace, to be able to use it you need to add:

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
```

I recommend using ReSharper which automatically resolves missing C#'s namespaces.